# Signed message in ethers not recovered in solidity

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, signature, ecdsa

In Ethers.js i am signing a message which I want to recover in Solidity using the ECDSA library from openzeppeling, I have one version which works but when I try the same method in which the parameters are arrays I do not get the correct address recovered.

**1) The Working Version**  (Signing a message without uint256 arrays)

In ethers.js

```
    // Test single sign
    let message1 = ethers.utils.solidityPack(
        ["uint256","uint256","uint256"],
        [ 1,2,123456789]
    );

    message1 = ethers.utils.solidityKeccak256(["bytes"], [message1]);
    const signature1 = await mintData.signer.signMessage(ethers.utils.arrayify(message1));
    const testSignature1 = await collection.testSignature1(1,2,signature1);
    console.log('Verify hash: ', message1, testSignature1);
```

Recover in Solidity:

```
    function testSignature1(
        uint256 param1,
        uint256 param2,
        bytes memory _signature
    )
        public
        view
        returns ( bytes32 msgHash )
    {
        uint256 nonce = 123456789;
        
        bytes32 msgHash = keccak256(
            abi.encode(
                param1,
                param2,
                nonce
            )
        );
        address signer = msgHash.toEthSignedMessageHash().recover(_signature);
        console.log("signer: ", signer);
        return msgHash;
    }
```

The above code recovers the correct signer.

**2) The non working Version**  (Signing a message with uint256 arrays)

In ethers.js

```
    let message2 = ethers.utils.solidityPack(
        [
            "uint256[]",
            "uint256[]",
            "uint256"
        ],
        [
            [1,1],
            [2,2],
            123456789
        ]
    );

    message2 = ethers.utils.solidityKeccak256(["bytes"], [message2]);
    console.log("signer: ", signer);
    const signature2 = await mintData.signer.signMessage(ethers.utils.arrayify(message2));
    const testSignature2 = await collection.testSignature2(1,2,signature2);
    console.log('Verify hash: ', message2, testSignature2);
```

Solidity:

```
      function testSignature2(
           bytes memory _signature,
           uint256[] memory param1,
           uint256[] memory param2
    )
        public
        view
        returns ( bytes32 msgHash )
    {   
        uint256 nonce = 123456789;
        
        bytes32 msgHash = keccak256(
            abi.encode(
                param1,
                param2,
                nonce
            )
        );
        address signer = msgHash.toEthSignedMessageHash().recover(_signature);
        console.log("signer: ", signer);
        return msgHash;
    }
```

The second method does not recover the correct signer address in solidity and I cannot figure out why.  With Ethers.js I can recover the correct address with:

```
 ethers.utils.verifyMessage(message2,signature2));
```

Also the hash that is generated from ethers.js and the solidityPack with keccak256 in solidity are the same, as per below console output:

```
Verify hash:  0x086e3fc9b14f58aca90fb67e71e7f5c3bf1fc5a971488c7681eda8620848f651 0x086e3fc9b14f58aca90fb67e71e7f5c3bf1fc5a971488c7681eda8620848f651
Verify hash:  0x80b1d198523e1dd6e131e71dc5c53d3af997775699592708dde607e4c69d5720 0x086e3fc9b14f58aca90fb67e71e7f5c3bf1fc5a971488c7681eda8620848f651
```

Comment: You're calling `collection.testSignature1` and not `collection.testSignature2` in the second example. Is that a typo?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out  @0xSanson,  it still was not working but I figured out that the has is not the same with my second method, I found the resolution though and will post the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem, the hashes were not the same (Corrected the mistake pointed out by @OxSanson) and I found out that in order to get the same hash and verify I had to change the way I am encoding the variables in Solidity.

Instead of using abi.encode I used abi.encodePacked instead:

```
bytes32 msgHash = keccak256(
            abi.encodePacked(
                param1,
                param2,
                nonce
            )
        );
```

Comment: The only drawback from what I have read is that encodePacked can cause a hash collision for dynamic types, would the dynamic uint256[] arrays I use be considered a dynamic type and could using encodePacked in my example open a security vulnerability ?